# Find cumulative distribution function of two independent exponential random variables $X$ and $Y$

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent exponential random variable with rates $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$, respectively. What is the cumulative distribution function of $\frac{X}{Y}$?

I know that the joint density function is 
$f(x,y) = (\lambda_1 e^{-\lambda_1 x})(\lambda_2 e^{-\lambda_2 x})$

can I just take the integral of  $\frac{(\lambda_1 e^{-\lambda_1 x})} {(\lambda_2 e^{-\lambda_2 x})}$ to find the c.d.f of $\frac{X}{Y}$?

Comment: No, you cannot take the integral that you propose. For $a > 0$, you need to find $P\{X/Y \leq a\} = P\{X \leq aY\}$. Can you find the region in the first quadrant where the coordinates $(x,y)$ satisfy $x \leq ay$? Can you integrate the joint density function over this region?

Comment: $P(X/Y \leq a) = P(X \leq aY) = $$\iint_{x < ay}  (\lambda_1 e^{-\lambda_1 x})(\lambda_2 e^{-\lambda_2 x}) dx dy$ = $\int_{y=0}^{\infty} \int_{x=0}^{ay}  (\lambda_1 e^{-\lambda_1 x})(\lambda_2 e^{-\lambda_2 x}) dx dy$    Am I on the right track?

Comment: You are (except the two $e^{-\lambda_2x}$ which should read $e^{-\lambda_2y}$). Can you carry on?

Comment: @Did I have asked a similar question [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/252354/cdf-of-fracx-1x-2x-1x-2a-where-x-1-and-x-2-have-exp-distributions). I have used the approach proposed here and  have tried to calculate the CDF in my case. Could you please check it and give me your feedback (or even you can answer the question there). Thank you!

Comment: @din See there.